# Rtti invoke a class method says invalid type cast

Tags: delphi, casting, rtti, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have made a unit that's very generic and settings objects in this are all TObjects i don't want to make uses of any units that's why i'm doing this. So my approach is to use RTTI to call everything. But now i face a problem where i can call all the functions and give arguments and everything but when the method is a class procedure/function i can't call it and it says invalid type cast.

I checked on embarcadero's website it says that when we call rtti.invoke on a classmethod we have to set the first argument in Args as a class reference. I tried that but it doesn't work. Take a look at my code:

```
function TSomething.ExecMethodAndRet(MethodName: string;
  Args: array of TValue): TObjectList<TObject>;
var
 R : TRttiContext;
 T : TRttiType;
 M : TRttiMethod;
 lArgs : array of TValue;
 i : integer;
begin
  T := R.GetType(MainObj.ClassInfo);
  for M in t.GetMethods do
    if (m.Parent = t) and (UpperCase(m.Name) = UpperCase(MethodName))then
    begin
      if (m.IsClassMethod) then
      begin
        for I := 0 to Length(Args) do
          lArgs := [args[i]];
        lArgs := [MainObj] + lArgs;
        result := M.Invoke(MainObj, Args).AsType<TObjectList<TObject>>; <- this will say invalid type cast
      end
      else
        result := M.Invoke(MainObj, Args).AsType<TObjectList<TObject>>; <- this one works when it's not a classMethod that's why i made a condition
    end;
end;
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. Maybe it's not possible to do it without knowing the type of the object. My Main Obj is a TObject that is of the required type and i can call the methods of it. But That class procedure is really giving me a hard time.

Someone knows how i could achieve this?

Comment: You need to pass the reference to the class type, not the object instance.

Comment: How can i get the actual class reference of the the object it hold and not TObject?

Comment: FWIW use `SameText` instead comparing result of `UpperCase` - avoids extra string allocations. And call `GetDeclaredMethods` if you only want the methods of this type anyway.

Comment: @StefanGlienke But is it the same text if i write "create" and "Create"? I didn't try but apparenly Same text is comparing pointers and i don't think those two are the same pointers.

Comment: Just read the documentation, hmkay: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.SameText

Comment: @StefanGlienke "the result will be False for the Windows platform, and True for the OSX, iOS and Android platforms". Not sure about this, i'll stay with UpperCase. Not like we have limited memory those days. At least i know it will work, as it's a rest service i prefer having something that works on all machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the instance use

```
M.Invoke(MainObj.ClassType,
```